# r analogous to sql inner join selection

Tags: sql, r

Suppose we have the contents of tables x and y in two dataframes in R. Which is the suggested way to perform an operation like the following in sql:

```
Select x.X1, x.X2, y.X3
into z
from x inner join y on x.X1 = y.X1
```

I tried the following in R. Is there a better way? 
Thank you

```
x<-data.frame(cbind('X1'=c(5,9,7,6,4,8,3,1,10,2),'X2'=c(5,9,7,6,4,8,3,1,10,2)^2))
y<-data.frame(cbind('X1'=c(9,5,8,2),'X3'=c('nine','five','eight','two')))

z<-cbind(x[which(x$X1 %in% (y$X1)), c(1:2)][order(x[which(x$X1 %in% (y$X1)), c(1:2)]$X1),],y[order(y$X1),2])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was [already answered on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-data-frames-in-r-inner-outer-left-right).

Beyond merge, if you're more comfortable with SQL you should check out the sqldf package, which allows you to run SQL queries on data frames.

```
 library(sqldf)
 z <- sqldf("SELECT X1, X2, X3 FROM x JOIN y
      USING(X1)")
```

That said, you will be better off learning the base R functions (merge, intersect, union, etc.) in the long run.

Comment: interesting, I did know of RMySQL, but not of sqldf.. looks cool.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it was easy
    merge(x,y)